# Configure Swagger javax validation Constraints on DTOs

Tags: java, validation, swagger

I'm using Swagger (1.5.8).  I want my `swagger.json` definition to detect the `javax.validation` [JSR-303](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/) annotations on my DTOs, so that I can document my API's validation constraints.

I would expect a `@Min` annotation ([like this example](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-jaxrs/src/test/java/io/swagger/resources/ResourceWithValidation.java)) would show something about the minimum value (44), but it does not.

```
@POST
@ApiOperation(value = "post", httpMethod = "POST")
public Response post(
        @QueryParam("id") @NotNull @Min(44) Integer id) {...}
```

The resulting `swagger.json` for this is:

```
"/foo": {
  "post": {
    "operationId": "post",
    ...
    "parameters": [
      {
        "in": "body",
        "name": "id",
        "description": "id",
        "required": false,
        "schema": {
          "type": "integer",
          "format": "int32"
        }
      }
```

Swagger has [closed the pull request for this functionality](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/pull/1618), but I'm unclear where/how it is able to be consumed in the Swagger definition.

I want to be able to do things like:

### FooController

```
@POST
public void postFoo(@Valid @RequestBody FooDTO fooDto) {...}
```

### FooDTO

```
public class FooDTO {
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    private Integer myInt;
}
```

### Desired/Expected swagger.json Output:

```
"FooDTO": {
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "myInt"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "myInt": {
      "type": "number",
      "format": "integer",
      "minimum": "1",
      "maximum": "100",
 ...
```

What's the preferred way to configure Swagger Modules/Plugins to enable things like [`ModelResolver`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-core/src/main/java/io/swagger/jackson/ModelResolver.java) and [`BeanValidator`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-hibernate-validations/src/main/java/io/swagger/validator/BeanValidator.java), so that they'll inspect the annotations on my DTO's?

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this?

Comment: @EuanMilton: It sounds like the feature is scheduled for an upcoming minor release, so I opted to wait.

Comment: Still can't find a proper solution for this!

Comment: why are you validating on DTO instead of POJO? It's not good design pattern.

Comment: Looking at the TestNG code for this change, I see that all the tests also include an @ApiParam annotation on the parameter. Does adding that make a difference?

Comment: This is working now in more recent swagger versions. Voting to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Latest, as of now, Swagger-Core version 1.5.19 perfectly supports this:

DTO object similar to this:

```
public class SampleDTO {

    @Min(value = 5)
    @Max(value = 10)
    @NotNull
    private Integer integer;

    @NotNull
    private String string;

    //...

}
```

Will generate **swagger.json** similar to this:

```
...

 "definitions" : {
    "SampleDTO" : {
      "type" : "object",
      "required" : [ "integer", "string" ],
      "properties" : {
        "integer" : {
          "type" : "integer",
          "format" : "int32",
          "minimum" : 5,
          "maximum" : 10
        },
        "string" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },

...
```

Comment: That's cool, but what if I want to use one of the other annotations. Is there a reference you can give me? I couldn't find it in the docs.

Comment: If you were to generate a DTO from the example swagger.json you show, would that DTO actually enforce those constraints?

Answer (score -1):

I browsed documentation. From my perspective, with swagger 1.x you have to use `@QueryParam` validation with `@ApiParam` in additional, like in this test case example:

```
@GET
@Path("/swagger-and-303")
@ApiOperation(value = "Get",
        httpMethod = "GET")
public Response getTestSwaggerAnd303(
        @ApiParam(value = "sample param data", required = false, allowableValues = "range[7, infinity]")
        @QueryParam("id") @NotNull @Min(5) Integer id) throws WebApplicationException {...`
```

In additional you can try to use @ApiImplicitParam in your specific case.